# Solution for server based image matching?

Tags: image-processing

Looking for a way to match images. User uploads an image to a web server; server compares to a database or folder of images and indicates if a match was found. Will never be an exact pixel for pixel match; think face-matching photos. Does not need to be synchronous (eg, matches can be sent to use minutes after they upload). Open to any technology - PHP ASP java whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There still isn't a best solution for face matching - see [opencv](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceRecognition) for a list of starting points for code and articles

Comment: This certainly does seem to be the case. Rats.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do real commercial face matching http://www.luxand.com/ have excellent libraries for a price.

Answer (score -1):

Java has good api called JAI to deal with images of various encodings,

1. First you need to read image stream. Store the matrix of pixel data i.e pixel data of each row X column in db of source images.
2. Once the any image is loaded you can retrieve pixel data and compare it with the same. Use lucene for indexing the documents which store this pixel data.

Comment: Comparing pixel values, especially for a compressed image format isn't going to find faces

Comment: For Image matching patterns and other image processing related algorithms, they use pixel data. I have myself developed an algorithm for Image thinning using 2-step and Fully parallel techniques.